# Is there a way to join these two tables in the desired format?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, data-modeling

I am trying to calculate interest rates for some of my opps and my tables structure looks like below using SQL, I am using redshift.

I am beginner and would appreciate any leads,

This is the user by territory and date table:

[image]

This is the interest rate by territory and date:

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bwn4.png is the desired table in this case with the additional column amount_with_interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use JOIN - read more about different type of joins.
Sample how to solve this proble:

```
Select ut.*
, ut.loan * ir.interest_rate
from
user_by_territory_Table as ut join
interest_Rate_table as ir 
on ut.territory = ir.territory
and ut.close_date = ir.close_date
```

Comment: Correct answer. However, care needs to be taken if the dates do not match exactly between both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use VIEWS and create a new virtual table (view) that will be more efficient. using view you can also search and manipulate on the output table. :)